# Function that provides one very large single oscillation before settling

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a function that is akin in behaviour to a second order differential equation but which, in response to a step input and when given suitable coefficients, provides one large overshoot and then settles.

I need to be able to control the period of the single oscillation and the overshoot should be something in the order of 2 to 6 times the input step size.

I imagine it as a spring-mass-damper system in which the damping grows with time such that it is very light initially and then controls the mass approximately critically as it returns from its overshoot.

I thought perhaps I could create a composite trigonometric function but I don't seem to have got anywhere with that.

Thanks.

Simon.

Comment: When you say akin in behaviour to a second order differential equation, do you have one specifically in mind? If you do, then perhaps the solution to that equation is the function you seek.